# Unwinding shortened URLs with Python, SQLite, and multithreading

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, sqlite

I spent the last couple of days reading/researching and learning sqlite and python multithreading.

I'm unwinding shortened urls stored in a sql table with three fields...
**id** | **url_starting** | **url_unwound**

The code chunks the database results, sends the chunk to a thread pool of the same chunk size, unwinds the urls and writes the results back to the database, then iterates to the next chunk.

I'm happy with the results but am looking for feedback as this is my first attempt.

General thoughts are greatly appreciated.
Also, any ideas on making the `future_to_url =` section more readable would be great.

```
import time
import os
import sqlite3
from datetime import datetime
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen


class MyDatabase(object):
    def __init__(self, db):
        self.__conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
        self.__conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row  # https://stackoverflow.com/a/41920171/25197
        self.__conn.execute('pragma foreign_keys = on')
        self.__conn.commit()
        self.__cursor = self.__conn.cursor()

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __del__(self):
        self.__conn.close()

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self.__conn.close()

    def query(self, arg):
        self.__cursor.execute(arg)
        self.__conn.commit()
        return self.__cursor

    def updateUnwoundUrl(self, url_starting, url_unwound):
        self.__cursor.execute(
            'UPDATE url SET url_unwound = ? WHERE url_starting = ?', (url_unwound, url_starting))
        self.__conn.commit()
        return self.__cursor


def unwindUrl(starting_url, timeout):
    try:
        hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)'}
        response = urlopen(Request(starting_url, headers=hdr), timeout=timeout)
        unwound_url = response.geturl()

    # For any http error just return error. Deal with specifics later.
    except Exception:
        unwound_url = 'error'

    return unwound_url


def chunk_iter(iterable, chunk_size):
    it = iter(iterable)
    while True:
        chunk = tuple(next(it) for _ in range(chunk_size))
        if not chunk:
            break
        yield chunk


def unwindUrls(workers=100, request_timeout=10):
    relative_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    my_db_path = os.path.join(relative_path, 'database', 'my.db')

    with MyDatabase(my_db_path) as my_db:
        wound_urls = my_db.query(
            'SELECT url_starting, id FROM url WHERE url_unwound IS NULL ORDER BY id ASC').fetchall()

        chunk_count = len(wound_urls) / workers
        for i, wound_urls_chunk in enumerate(chunk_iter(wound_urls, workers), start=1):

            print('starting chunk {0} of {1} at {2}'.format(
                i, chunk_count, datetime.now().strftime("%I:%M:%S %p")))

            with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=workers) as executor:
                future_to_url = {executor.submit(
                    unwindUrl, row['url_starting'], request_timeout): row['url_starting'] for row in wound_urls_chunk}

                for future in as_completed(future_to_url):
                    try:
                        url_starting = future_to_url[future]
                        url_unwound = future.result()
                        my_db.updateUnwoundUrl(url_starting, url_unwound)
                        # print('starting: {0} unwound: {1}'.format(url_starting, url_unwound))
                    except Exception as exc:
                        print('!! {0}'.format(exc))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    startTime = time.time()
    unwindUrls()
    print('==--- unwind_urls took {0} seconds. ---=='.format(round(time.time() - startTime)))
```

Answer (score 4):

## `__`

There is liitle need for the `__`. A single `_` should suffice to make people clear it's a private attribute. If they really want to use it, `__` won't stop the access

## Linelength

Especially the lines with queries are too long. Can't you make those queries multiline?

From:

```
def updateUnwoundUrl(self, url_starting, url_unwound):
    self.__cursor.execute(
        'UPDATE url SET url_unwound = ? WHERE url_starting = ?', (url_unwound, url_starting))
    self.__conn.commit()
    return self.__cursor
```

to:

```
def updateUnwoundUrl(self, url_starting, url_unwound):
    self.__cursor.execute(
        '''UPDATE url 
           SET url_unwound = ? 
           WHERE url_starting = ?
        '''
        , (url_unwound, url_starting)
    )
    self.__conn.commit()
    return self.__cursor
```

## Hoist the IO

If ever you want to change the db format to something else, you will need to change the internals of the code and how the `my_db_path` is made.

To change this, I would follow the tips from [this talk](http://rhodesmill.org/brandon/talks/#hoist).

## Database path

```
def unwindUrls(workers=100, request_timeout=10):
    relative_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    my_db_path = os.path.join(relative_path, 'database', 'my.db')
```

First, I would use `my_db_path` to handle filepaths.

Secondly I would add `relative_path` as an an argument, with `Path('.')` as default argument, this way you can specify the path.

```
def unwindUrls(workers=100, request_timeout=10):
    relative_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    my_db_path = os.path.join(relative_path, 'database', 'my.db')
    with MyDatabase(my_db_path) as my_db:

...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unwindUrls()
```

To:

```
def unwindUrls(my_db, workers=100, request_timeout=10):

...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_db_path = pathlib.Path('.') / 'database' / 'my.db'
    with MyDatabase(my_db_path) as my_db:
        unwindUrls(my_db)
```

## `chunk_iter`

```
def chunk_iter(iterable, chunk_size):
    it = iter(iterable)
    while True:
        chunk = tuple(next(it) for _ in range(chunk_size))
        if not chunk:
            break
        yield chunk
```

raises a `Warning` in Python 3.6

> C:\miniconda3\envs\test_env\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:4:
>   DeprecationWarning: generator 'chunk_iter..' raised
>   StopIteration   after removing the cwd from sys.path.

Better to use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice)

```
def chunk_iter(iterable, chunk_size):
    it = iter(iterable)
    while True:
        chunk = tuple(islice(it, chunk_size))
        if not chunk:
            return
        yield chunk
```

## Exception

a few time you use `except Exception`. This is way too broad. You should specify which Exceptions you want to catch

Comment: Hi @Maarten. Thanks for the review!  I've implemented everything you mentioned. Thanks for pointing out `islice` and `pathlib`. I wasn't yet aware of either.

Answer (score 1):

### `future_to_url =`

To answer my own question on this part...
I ended up renaming some variables and using a loop instead of a comprehension to fill the dictionary.
I feel it's more readable in this case.

Instead of this...

```
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=workers) as executor:
    future_to_url = {executor.submit(
        unwindUrl, row['url_starting'], request_timeout): row['url_starting'] for row in wound_urls_chunk}

    for future in as_completed(future_to_url):
        try:
            url_starting = future_to_url[future]
            url_unwound = future.result()
            my_db.updateUnwoundUrl(url_starting, url_unwound)
        except Exception as exc:
            print('!! {0}'.format(exc))
```

This...

```
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=workers) as executor:
    thread_pool = {}
    for row in wound_urls_chunk:
        unwindUrl_thread = executor.submit(unwindUrl, row['url_starting'], timeout)
        thread_pool[unwindUrl_thread] = row['url_starting']

    for completed_thread in as_completed(thread_pool):
        try:
            url_starting = thread_pool[completed_thread]
            url_unwound = completed_thread.result()
            my_db.updateUnwoundUrl(url_starting, url_unwound)
        except Exception as exc:
            print('!! {0}'.format(exc))
```